# Universal property for the "countably-direct" sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, universal-property

Let $(E_i)_{i \in I}$ be a non-empty collection of modules over a given ring $R$ (this could be generalized to other suitable categories, but I won't consider these here).
We define the *countably-direct sum* by taking all the elements of the product $\prod_{i \in I} E_i$ having at most countably many non-zero components:
$$ \underset{i \in I}{\Large \boxplus}\;  E_i :=
\left\{x \in \prod_{i \in I} E_i  \;\middle|\;
\#\{i \in I : x_i \neq 0\} ≤ \aleph_0 \right\}$$

My question is:

> Is there a universal property (using objects and morphisms in $\mathsf{Mod}_R$) characterizing the countably-direct sum, as there is for the direct sum?

---

I recall the universal property for direct sums, a.k.a. [coproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) :

For any object $M$ and any collection of morphisms $f_i : E_i \to M$ there exists a unique morphism $f : \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} E_i \to M$ such that $f_i = f \circ r_i$ for all $i \in I$ (where $r_j : E_j \to \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} E_i$ denotes the canonical inclusion).

$$\begin{array}{center}
    \quad\qquad   \bigoplus_{j \in I} E_j \;\dashrightarrow M \\
    \quad\qquad \uparrow   r_i  \, \, \, \, \, \, \nearrow f_i \\
            E_i    \\
\end{array}$$

The definition of universal property can be more general than [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63150), because we are dealing with a family of objects (see for instance [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29#Limits) diagrams).
Related questions: [What things can be defined in terms of universal properties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164610), [How to define $A\uparrow B$ with a universal property as well as $A\oplus B$, $A\times B$, $A^B$ in category theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028056).

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947045) question and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/10249) MO answer, I tried to show that the countably-direct sum doesn't satisfy the universal property of direct sums, but I was stuck.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In case $I$ is countable this is just the product. By a cardinally argument we know that a infinite countable products are not always the direct sum, so it can not satisfy the universal property of direct sums. What we know is that the countably-direct sum is kind of the union of the countable products. Thus the countably-direct sum should be the direct limit of all those countable products. Since products and direct limits have universal properties you get at least some kind of a universal property.

Comment: Well. Kind of, but a colimit of a limit doesn't have a universal property in its own right.

Comment: The finiteness thing in the coproduct comes in because the operations in hand are finitary. If we considered "$\sigma$-modules" (over "$\sigma$-rings"), their coproduct would be just the countably direct sum.

Comment: @Berci : what do you mean by "$\sigma$-modules"?